# Getting Progress Updates using HttpWebRequest and TPL (Tasks)

Tags: wpf, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library, progress

I would like to track the progress of a download taking place on a separate thread. I know that System.Net.WebClient has a DownloadStringAsync method, but it doesn't work directly with the new TPL types (TaskFactory, Task, etc.).

- Can progress be tracked using the HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes?
- What's the best class for tracking progress? The less overhead the better.
- Are there times when the size of the response is unknown, aka, progress can't be tracked?
- What's the best way to synchronize with the UI thread whenever progress is made?

Most examples show Tasks updating the UI only after the entire task is complete. These examples use continuations taking a UI synchronization context that avoids needing to work with a Dispatcher directly.

The idea is to show a grid view (in WPF) with all the downloads with progress bars. I am going to adding new rows and updating progress bars all the time. I'm trying to avoid turning this code into a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DownloadStringAsync and the other event  methods work very well with TPL in .NET 4.0 (check for EAP and TPL). In general, TPL does support event async programming through the TaskCompletionSource. The Begin/EndXXX model (APM) is supported through the Task.FromAsync method. You can find a detailed description [TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx).

The [ParallelExtensionExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/05/04/10007557.aspx) library has a set of WebClient extensions methods like DownloadStringTask that return a task which completes when the appropriate event is fired.

The following code will create a Task that will complete when download finishes:

```
    public Task<string> DownloadStringTask(WebClient client,Uri uri)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, a) => tcs.SetResult(a.Result);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

As for updating the UI, you can easily use the DownloadProgressChanged event to provide feedback,eg:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, a) => Console.WriteLine("{0}",a.ProgressPercentage);

    var task = DownloadStringTask(client,new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
    var write=task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Got {0} chars", t.Result.Length));
    write.Wait();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you use data binding to provide the progress values to your progress bars, you can just update the progress value properties. If you update the progress bars directly (not a good idea), you will have to marshal the call to the UI thread using the progress bar's dispatcher, eg. like this

```
    void UpdateProgress(int percent)
    {
        if (progressBar1.CheckAccess())
            progressBar1.Value = percent;
        else
        {                
            progressBar1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>UpdateProgress(percent)));
        }
    }
    ....
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, a) => UpdateProgress(a.ProgressPercentage);
```